# Bad credentials Exception | Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

Trying to use Spring security for authentication process, but getting `Bad credentials` exception.here is how I have defined things in my `spring-security.xml` file

```
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
   class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager id="customerAuthenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customerDetailsService">
     <password-encoder hash="sha" />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

`customerDetailsService` is our own implementation being provided to spring security.In my Java code while registering user, I am encoding provided password before adding password to Database something like

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;
 @Autowired
 private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
 customerModel.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(customer.getPwd(), null));
```

When I tried to debug my application, it seems Spring is calling `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` authenticate method  and when its performing additionalAuthenticationCheck with  `additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);` of `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, it throwing Bad credential exception at following point

```
if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
 logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
    throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
 }
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong and what needs to be done here to put things in right place, I already checked customer is there in database and password is encoded.

Comment: Two beans with same id? Try to use `ref` attribute of `password-encoder`.

Comment: @AleksandrM: Thanks, that just a typo , i just copy pasted it twice :D

Comment: Ok. Have you tried with ref?

Comment: @AleksandrM:I told you that my my typo..i am able to solve that issue, it was due to some wrong values being passed from from ;)

Comment: Actually I meant ref in password-encoder. :)

Comment: @AleksandrM: Oh..not yet will change...good catch

Answer (score 1):

Alter your password-encoder declaration from

```
<password-encoder hash="sha" />
```

to

```
<password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
```

Check if your customerDetailsService loads user credential from database. 
If you still getting bad credentials exception: add erase-credentials="false" to your authenticationManager.

```
<authentication-manager id="customerAuthenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customerDetailsService">
     <password-encoder hash="sha" />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: my customer detail service is loading user from database correctly, issue is when `additionalAuthenticationChecks` is getting called, still I will try to change things as per your suggestion and see what happened